# How can i properly format php array to json?

Tags: php, json

Here is my code. I'm trying to scrape a table.

```
$page = file_get_contents('https://www.jncb.com/Support/Help-Resources/Foreign-Exchange-Services');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $page;
$data = array();
$fx = array();
$cnt = 0;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$my_xpath_query = "//table//tbody[contains(@class, 'FxRContainer')]//td";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);


foreach ($result_rows as $key=>$result_object) {  
    $data[] = $result_object->nodeValue;
} 

for ($i=0; $i < 28; ++$i) { 
    if( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
        $fx[] = $data[$i];
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < 14; ++$i) { 
    if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
        $fx[$i] = substr($fx[$i], 6);
    }
}

print_r($fx);
echo json_encode($fx, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here are my results:

```
[
   "USD",
   "120.00",
   "GBP",
   "171.20",
   "CAD",
   "95.50",
   "EUR",
   "148.30",
   "KYD",
   "0.00",
   "TTD",
   "0.00",
   "JPY",
   "1.11"
]
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to format the values in the array properly so i can out to json properly.

Comment: And what is __properly__?

Comment: **properly** is having the brackets and colons to separate the object and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.

In order to create JSON from PHP you need an `associative array`. Right now you have a standard array.

For example:

```
$associative_array = [
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'amount' => 120.00
];
```

OR

```
$associative_array = [
   'USD' => 120.00
];
```

The exact example for your case:

```
foreach($result_rows as $key => $result_object) {
    // took a guess here
    // not entirely sure if you want the $key or the $result_object->nodeValue to be substr'd
    $data[$key] = substr($result_object->nodeValue, 6);
}
```

Then you can use `json_encode()` to encode it to a JSON object:

```
$json = json_encode($associative_array);
```

Comment: i have  been trying to achieve:
$associative_array = [
   'USD' => 120.00
];

How can i convert my simple array to the associative array?

Comment: I just added to my answer, but basically you need to use the `$key` part of your `foreach` loop to build the keys in your associative array.